# Queryset filter using Case/When for Model field, not field value

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-oscar

I would like to combine two querysets, or better, make only one using the Case/When syntax for a specific case.

I have seen in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case) that it can be use for queryset filtering, not only annotate, which is exactly what I need. However, I want to use the Case/When for the model field itself, not the value of the field.

The project is an e-commerce, I use django-oscar so the models are quite big to post them here. The thing to know is that a basket line refers to a product, and a product can either be parent, child or standalone.

Here is my code :

```
self.in_stock_lines = basket.lines.filter(product__product_class__track_stock=True, is_customized=False)
```

Thing is, if the basket line relates to a product being a child, the field I must filter on is  `product__parent__product_class__track_stock`, whereas if it relates to a standalone product (having not parent), it stays `product__product_class__track_stock` as in my initial queryset.

Is there a way to do this ? Or do I have no choice but combine the two querysets using `itertools.chain()` for example ?

Comment: Please post your model..... also, take a look at the mptt, it may be easier to achieve what you are looking for. What happens when you have a Product of a Product of a Product?... https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt

Comment: I edited my question, I think the models are too big to post them here (e-commerce). But there cannot be a product of a product of a product, it stands to parent/child relationship or standalone (by itself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`Q`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) objects for that.

```
from django.db.models import Q

basket.lines.filter(
  Q(product_parent__isnull=True, product__product_class__track_stock=True) | 
  Q(product__parent__product_class__track_stock=True), is_customized=False)
```